# The number of cases $(0, 0)$ moves by either $(1,1)$ or $(1,-1)$, in $2n$ steps, without touching $x$-axis again.

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving combinatorics problems when I ran into this shady statement:

The number of cases $(0, 0)$ moves by either $(1, 1)$ or $(1, -1)$, in $2n$ steps, without touching $x$-axis again is $\binom{2n}{n}$.

I tried in vain to understand this result. It produces a modified Pascal's triangle and it gives the right answer. How to prove this statement using a combinatorical proof?

Comment: Since you are talking about the point avoiding the $x$-axis, don't you mean moving either by $(1,1)$ or $(1,-1)$? The way you have it the point will always move up by $1$ and never come back down to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Should it be $(1, -1)$ instead of $(-1, 1)$? If it were $(-1, 1)$, since it goes up all the time, it will of course never touch the x-axis.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My silly mistake:(

Comment: May be I misunderstand what is meant by a **case**. What are the ${2\choose 1}$ cases when n = 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on the scenario where $Y_1=1$. The key is to use refection principle on the next $2n-1$ moves.

There will be 4 all inclusive and mutually exclusive scenarios:

1. $Y_i>0$ for all $i$
2. $Y_n=0$, of course x-axis must have been touched
3. $Y_n<0$, of course x-axis must have been touched
4. $Y_n>0$ and $\exists i$ s.t. $Y_i=0$, i.e. x-axis is touched

Let $N_i$ be the number of paths that fall in scenario i.

$N_2=C_{2n-1}^n$

$N_3=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}C_{2n-1}^k$

With reflection principle, we have $N_3=N_4$.

Since $N_1+N_2+N_3+N_4=2^{2n-1}$,

$N_1=2^{2n-1}-C_{2n-1}^n-2\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}C_{2n-1}^k=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}C_{2n-1}^k-C_{2n-1}^n-\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}C_{2n-1}^k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}C_{2n-1}^k=C_{2n-1}^{n-1}=\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{2(n!)^2}=\frac{C_{2n}^n}{2}$

Now adding the part where $Y_1=-1$, the total is $C_{2n}^n$.

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with generating functions, if one knows the generating functions for the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) and [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

Consider first paths that begin with $\langle 1,1\rangle$ and *do* hit the $x$-axis. Let $k\le n$ be the smallest positive integer such that the path hits the $x$-axis after $2k$ steps. Then the $2k$-th step was $\langle 1,-1\rangle$, and the $2k-2$ steps between the first and the $2k$-th steps form a Dyck path of length $2(k-1)$. There are $C_k$ such paths, where $C_k$ is the $k$-th Catalan number, and there are $2^{n-1-k}$ ways to continue the path after it first returns to the $x$-axis, so there are $2^{n-1-k}C_k$ paths that start with $\langle 1,1\rangle$ and first return to the $x$-axis after $2k$ steps. Doubling this to account for ‘bad’ paths that start with $\langle 1,-1\rangle$, and summing over the possible values of $k$, we find that there are

$$b_n=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{2(n-1-k)}C_k$$

bad paths of length $2n$.

Let

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}C_nx^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\;,$$

the generating function for the Catalan numbers, and

$$g(x)=2\sum_{n\ge 0}4^nx^n=\frac2{1-4x}\;.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n&=2\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}4^{n-1-k}C_kx^n\\\\
&=xf(x)g(x)\\\\
&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{1-4x}\\\\
&=\frac1{1-4x}-\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}4^nx^n-\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2n}nx^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(2^{2n}-\binom{2n}n\right)x^n\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$b_n=2^{2n}-\binom{2n}n\;.$$

Since there are $2^{2n}$ paths of length $2n$ altogether, there must be $\dbinom{2n}n$ that don’t return to the $x$-axis.